# GitHub: Pull Requests raised by me?

Tags: git, github

How can I view all the PR's raised by me -> especially count statistics?

Something like

- PR's raised by me

  - How many are merged?
  - How many are closed?
- PR's raised to a specific repository, How many branches created etc... etc...

Does GitHub provide stats for a specific user?

Comment: Not sure what is wrong in the question which was added 11 months back where GITHUB haven't improved its UI with query mechanism. Hope the down voter care to comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PR's raised by me?

Login in github, just click `Pull requests`.

---

> How many are merged?

copy and paste this in search bar: `is:pr author:YOUR_USERNAME is:merged`

---

> How many are closed?

Do you mean unmeged? Use this one: `is:pr author:YOUR_USERNAME  is:unmerged is:closed`
Do you mean just closed? Use this one: `is:pr author:YOUR_USERNAME  is:closed`

---

> PR's raised to a specific repository?

Use this one: `is:pr author:YOUR_USERNAME repo:YOUR_REPO`

---

More details about searching in [github help documentation](https://help.github.com/categories/search)

Comment: Is there a way to have `YOUR_USERNAME` dynamically fill out based on the current user? Makes bookmarks for teams much nicer

Answer (score 1):

Once you sign in to git online , you can see a tab named as "public activity" after click on your username at top corner,  that list down all the PRs you created , merged etc